# Piping array elements into New-TimeSpan returning method not supported

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script that checks the last write times of some files, and if they're outside the time parameter I want them to be in, they send me a text. Here is the (working) way of how I used to do it:

```
$lastupdate = (Get-ChildItem N:\BYUI-played.xml).LastWriteTime
$currentdate = get-date
$difference =NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $lastupdate –End $currentdate

IF ($difference -gt "0.0:31:0.0") {
$Sesherror = 1
Log-Write "$currentdate [ERROR] BYUI-JustPlayed is down"
}
```

Six times...and then an if at the bottom of the program would check to see the value of of `$Sesherror` and...well you can probably figure out the rest. Obviously cumbersome and not very well written. So, I decided to refactor it, and I came up with what I thought was slick:

```
$lastupdate = @((Get-ChildItem N:\BYUI-played.xml).LastWriteTime,(Get-ChildItem N:\byui-now.xml).LastWriteTime,(Get-ChildItem N:\KBYR-played.xml).LastWriteTime,(Get-ChildItem N:\KBYR-now.xml).LastWriteTime,(Get-ChildItem N:\KBYI-played.xml).LastWriteTime,(Get-ChildItem N:\KBYI-now.xml).LastWriteTime)

Try {

$lastupdate | % {
        if (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $lastupdate –End $currentdate -gt "0.1:0:0.0") {
        $Sesherror = 1
        Log-Write "$currentdate [ERROR] $lastupdate is down"
        }}
        }
Catch {
Write-Warning "Something went wrong with the algorithim"
Write-Host "$ERROR" -foregroundcolor Red
Write-Warning "Terminating error. Shutting down."
cmd /c pause
exit
}
```

Again, polling the `$Sesherror` variable at the bottom. But, when that runs, I get six instances of this error message:

```
Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.DateTime' required by parameter 'Start'. Specified method is not supported.
```

So I have to assume it has something to do with the array being piped in as a "Time" type. But, I've echoed the array, and they all output a correct time type. So I guess the question is two fold:
1. Why won't the foreach loop accept an array?
2. If it never will, what is the best way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're using the array-valued `$lastupdate` variable in the `ForEach-Object` (`%`) script block rather than the automatic iteration variable `$_`.

Therefore you're passing an *array* to `New-TimeSpan`'s `-Start` parameter, which fails.

Additionally, several optimizations can be made to your script:

```
$files = 'N:\BYUI-played.xml', 'N:\byui-now.xml', 'N:\KBYR-played.xml', 'N:\KBYR-now.xml', 'N:\KBYI-played.xml', 'N:\KBYI-now.xml'
$lastupdate = @(Get-Item $files | % { $_.LastWriteTime })
$currentdate = get-date

Try {
  $lastupdate | % {
    if (($_ – $currentdate) -gt "0.1:0:0.0") {
      $Sesherror = 1
      Log-Write "$currentdate [ERROR] $lastupdate is down"
    }
  }
} Catch {
  Write-Warning "Something went wrong with the algorithm"
  Write-Host "$ERROR" -foregroundcolor Red
  Write-Warning "Terminating error. Shutting down."
  cmd /c pause
  exit
}
```

- `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item` accept an *array* of paths, so there's no need for a separate invocation for each file.
- Subtracting two `[datetime]` instances from one another implicitly returns a `[timespan]` instance - no need for `New-TimeSpan`.
- Additionally, you could construct a `[timespan]` instance based on `"0.1:0:0.0"` outside the loop and store it in a variable for use in the `-gt` comparison, so as to avoid having to convert the string value to a `[timespan]` instance in each loop iteration, though the real-world impact of this optimization may be negligible.

Comment: That's perfect! I didn't think about using `$_` and I will research more about your last point!